# Append column's data to another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to append everything in Field1 to Field2 and then make Field1 values NULL for all records in the table. I do not want to merge these fields into a single field, I still want both fields to remain.

Take the following example:

```
Field 1       Field 2
Test Value    NULL
NULL          Another Value
My Value      Current Value
```

I want to end up with:

```
Field 1       Field 2
NULL          Test Value
NULL          Another Value
NULL          Current ValueMyValue
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
UPDATE table
SET Field2 = isnull(Field2,'') + isnull(Field1,''), Field1 = NULL
```

What I would suggest if you are not sure about it is to wrap the update in a BEGIN TRAN, ROLLBACK like so:

```
BEGIN TRAN

SELECT * FROM thistable

UPDATE thistable
SET Field2 = isnull(Field2,'') + isnull(Field1,'')
, Field1 = NULL

SELECT * FROM thistable

ROLLBACK
```

That way you will get a view of what the query will do before it makes the change 'permanent'. Once you are happy change ROLLBACK to COMMIT and run again.

[VIEW DEMO HERE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9767e/2/0)

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Field2 = ISNULL(Field2, '') + ISNULL(Field1, '')
```

To join the values into Field2.

And

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Field1 = NULL
```

To clear out Field1 once you are sure the first script worked.

Answer (score 0):

How about a little something like this:

```
UPDATE <Table name> SET field_2 = CONCAT(field_2, field_1);
UPDATE <Table name> SET field_1 = NULL;
```